# Renaming files in a folder (linux)

Tags: linux, terminal, batch-rename

I have a different HTML files in a folder. How to rename the files so that they have the names of:
    1.html
    2.html
    3.html
    ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can make it:

```
i=1
for file in /your/folder/*
do
   mv $file ${i}.html
   i=$((i+1)) #((i++)) was giving errors (see comments)
done
```

It loops through all files in `/your/folder` and renames them according to the number `$i` that keeps increasing.

Comment: `((i++)) # or i=$((i+1)) or let i=i+1`

Comment: So we have a 3rd option. Do you know which one is the best?

Comment: Hard to say which is the best.  All perform arithmetic operations.  BTW, `let i++` is more readable IMHO.

Comment: This script is renamed only one file and all the others removed

Comment: Shouldn't be like that. I tested it and worked. Instead of `mv $file ${i}.html`, put `echo $file ${i}.html` to see what happens.

Comment: dmitry@dmitry-N250P:~/pages$ sh bash.sh
    bash.sh 1.html
    bash.sh: 5: bash.sh: i++: not found
    ...

Comment: It seems to me that it does not like the `((i++))` syntax. Instead, can you try with the `i=$((i+1))`?

Comment: You're welcome! Now @devnull we see that some of these syntaxes don't work in all cases. I edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#       batchrename - renames files like 01.ext, 02.ext ...
#   
#   format :  batchrename <list of files>
#        or:              -r <extension> <<list of files> or <dir>>
#   -r - recoursively
counter=0
extrec=""
if [ "$#" -lt "1" ]; then
    echo -e "\n\t\tUsage:\n\tbatchrename [opt]\nopt:"
    echo -e "-r <ext> <folder> (or file list) -- renames recoursively ALL files"
    echo -e "\tin folder <folder> (or by file list given)  with extension .<ext>"
    echo -e "<folder> -- renames ALL files in folder given"
    echo -e "<file list> -- renames ALL files of given filelist.\n\n"
    exit 0
fi
Name="$*"
if [ "$1" = "-r" ]; then
    extrec="$2"
    shift
    shift
    Name="$*"
    [ "$Name" = "" ] && Name="./"
fi
echo -e "\n\t\t\tRENAMING"

for file in $Name
do
file=`echo "$file" | sed "s/<>/ /g"`
    if [ -d "$file" ];then
    echo -e "\nDiving into \033[38m $file \033[39m"
    cd "$file"
    if [ "$extrec" != "" ]; then
        batchrename -r $extrec `ls -1 | sed "s/\ /<>/g"`
    else
        batchrename `ls -1 | sed "s/\ /<>/g"`   
    fi
    cd ../
    continue
    fi
    ext=`ext "$file"`
    if [ "$ext" = "ion" ]; then
    continue
    fi
    if [ "$extrec" = "" -o "$ext" = "$extrec" ];then
        counter=`expr $counter + 1`
    echo -e "Progress: $counter files\r\c"
        mv "$file" "rnmd$counter.$ext"
    fi
done
echo -e "\n\n\t\t\tENDING"
digits=`echo $counter|awk '{print length ($0)}'`
cnt=1
while [ $digits -gt $cnt ]
do
    f=`ls -S -1|grep "rnmd[0-9]\{$cnt\}\."`
    rename rnmd rnmd0 $f
    cnt=`expr $cnt + 1`
done
if [ "$counter" -gt "0" ]; then
    rename rnmd "" rnmd*
fi
echo -e "\n\t\t\tDone !!!\n"
```

After renaming all your files will looks like 001.file, 002.file, ... and so on. Amount of leading zeros depends on amount of files. So, after renaming `ls` will show right order of files!

It use intermediate script `ext`:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#       ext - returns file suffix (case-unsensitive)
#
File="$*"
if [ -d "$File" ]; then
    echo ""
    exit 0
fi
EXT=`echo $File|sed 's/.\{1,\}\.//g'`
if [ "$EXT" = "$File" ]; then
    EXT=""
fi
echo $EXT| tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar code, just to add to rename with the same prefix and append an incremental value

```
declare -i x=1
for f in $(find -type f); do 
  mv -v $f ${f%/*}/change_me_$x ;
  x=$x+1;
done
```